# Having a function run at random time intervals, web2py

Tags: python, time, web2py

Im currently making a program that would send random text messages at randomly generated times during the day. I first made my program in python and then realized that if I would like other people to sign up to receive messages, I would have to use some sort of online framework. (If anyone knowns a way to use my code in python without having to change it that would be amazing, but for now I have been trying to use web2py) I looked into scheduler but it does not seem to do what I have in mind. If anyone knows if there is a way to pass a time value into a function and have it run at that time, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: A `cron` job maybe? What is your server OS?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Apscheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html) module for cron-like scheduling of events in python - In their [example](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.2/cronschedule.html) it shows how to schedule some python code to run in a cron'ish way.

Still not sure about the random part though..

As for a web framework that may appeal to you (seeing you are familiar with Python already) you should really look into Django (or to keep things simple just use WSGI).

Best.

Comment: Thank you I will look into Django. I did see some stuff on crontab, I figured there might be an easier way

Comment: Alternatively check out Celery. It has periodic tasks like cron.

Comment: I just went and looked on our server to see what python module we use for cron-like scheduling. turns out i was mistaken when i said python-crontab as we actually use apscheduler. I am updating my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that actually you can use Scheduler and Tasks of web2py. I've never used it ;) but the documentation describes creation of a task to which you can pass parameters from your code - so something you need - and it should work fine for your needs:

`scheduler.queue_task('mytask', start_time=myrandomtime)`

So you need web2py's cron job, running every day and firing code similar to the above for each message to be sent (passing parameters you need, possibly message content and phone number, see examples in web2py book). This would be a daily creation of tasks which would be processed later by the scheduler.

You can also have a simpler solution, one daily cron job which prepares the queue of messages with random times for the next day and the second one which runs every, like, ten minutes, checks what awaits to be processed and sends messages. So, no Tasks. This way is a bit ugly though (consider a single processing which takes more then 10 minutes). You may also want to have and check some statuses of the messages to be processed (like pending, ongoing, done) to prevent a situation in which two jobs are working on the same message and to allow tracking progress of the processing. Anyway, you could use the cron method it in an early version of your software and later replace it by a better method :)

In any case, you should check expected number of messages to process and average processing time on your target platform - to make sure that the chosen method is quick enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but in case someone is interested, the answer is APScheduler blocking scheduler with jobs set to run in regular intervals with some jitter
See: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/interval.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32309670)